# Angular Ivy strictTemplates Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InputEvent'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ivy

I really don't understand what's
the problem is with this code

```
<input #quantity type="number" matInput formControlName="quantity" (input)="onQuantity($event, i)" placeholder="Quantity"/>

onQuantity(event: InputEvent, i: number) {
    if (!this.totals[i]) {
      this.totals[i] = { price: '0', quantity: 1 };
    }
    let value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    value = value ? value : '0';
    this.totals[i].quantity = parseInt(value, 10);
  }
```

The compiler get an error
Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InputEvent'.
and if I use

```
onQuantity(event: Event, i: number)
```

I get
Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'InputEvent': data, inputType, isComposing, detail, and 2 more.

so I don't known what way to turn :(
Can anyone help me, please?

### UPDATE

I have worked it out with

```
(input)="onQuantity(quantity.value, i)"
```

https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Answer (score 1):

use (input)="onQuantity($any($event), i)" in html template

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

change event belongs to InputEvent type interface

Try this:

```
onQuantity(event: InputEvent, i: number){}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but was my first try :( and give me Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InputEvent'.

Comment: Do you have both   "fullTemplateTypeCheck and  "strictDomEventTypes" are enabled in ts config?

Comment: I've got strictTemplates= true includes both

Comment: If you disbale strictDomEventTypes to false then it will not throw any error or else you have to wrap event to any type like this in template (input)="onQuantity($any($event), i)"

Comment: I know but the policy is strictTemplates= true :)

Comment: This is what they have mentioned in the documentation you can file an issue:

Comment: A type-checking error that you cannot resolve with any of the recommended methods can be the result of a bug in the template type-checker itself. If you get errors that require falling back to basic mode, it is likely to be such a bug. If this happens, please file an issue so the team can address it.

Comment: Check this:https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#troubleshooting-template-errors

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
onQuantity(event:InputEvent, i: number){
    // do your operation
  }
```

the type of event is InputEvent.
You can check it by using `console.log(event)`

For me it gives

[image: 1]